# OpenGLES With iOS

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I don't know how to setup OpenGLES for iOS in Xcode using the Swift programming language. I have no idea what to import and I've used http://www.swiftgl.org/ to learn. However, the imports in this come up as an error when imported and I'm not sure what to do. I've provided my problem below, I'm not sure which package is missing. Removing "CGLFW3" import then gives "SGLOpenGL" the same error. If a package is missing how do I install it?

I want to make a 3d game.

Import package error
[image: Import package error]